# Request in nodejs: Not redirecting

Tags: node.js, httprequest

Request module in nodejs is supposed to automatically redirect URL once it receives redirect code: 302 right? It is not redirecting and my app is receiving a status code=200 with the cookies not set. What can I set so that redirection is automatic thanks!

Here is the code:

```
request.get({
    url: uri,
    followAllRedirects: true,
    agentOptions: {
       key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private.pem'),
       cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/public.pem'),
       ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca.pem'),
       requestCert: true,
       // rejectUnauthorized: false,
       passphrase: 'passphrase',
    },
    jar: false});
```

Comment: Code Please. Don't let people guess what you have written.

Comment: `jar` is set to `false`, which would explain the "cookies not set". Also, the 200 status code isn't a redirect, so it either _did_ follow the redirect or it's not getting the correct HTTP status code from the server. Try turning in [debugging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#debugging).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were right. It was following the redirect and returning a 200 after that. I was thinking that url was going to automatically change after redirect but i guess not?